# What (if anything) can I say about the inverse of the matrix product B'AB if B is not square?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Suppose I have:

- a matrix $A$ with dimension $n \times n$
- a matrix $B$ with dimension $n \times m$.
- $C = B^{T}AB$.

I'm interested in finding an expression for $C^{-1}$ when $m < n$.

The motivation here is that in minimization code I'm writing I already have $A^{-1}$ computed, and if possible I'd like to compute $C^{-1}$ without doing an inversion. $B$ is very simple, and I can probably find expressions for inverses or SVDs/Eigenvalue decompositions of simple expressions of $B$ analytically.

If it helps, $B$ is the product of rearranged columns of the $n \times n$ identity matrix and the first $m$ columns of the $n \times n$ identity matrix. In other words, if you think about $A$ as a matrix of second derivatives of a function $f$, $C$ is the matrix of second derivatives of a subset of variables of $f$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Some added info in response to comments:

- In my case, A is symmetric positive definite

Comment: I'm afraid we can't say much in general, a special case would be when the column space of $B$ is invariant under $A$..

Comment: is $A$ symmetric?

Comment: You may have to find the inverse of the matrix $D$, where $D$ is an elementary matrix and $B=DM$ ($M$ should be $n\times m$ matrix as suggested. This should be straightforward (check) as the elementary matrices (the ones obtained by performing a row operation on identity matrix) have inverses which can be found easily (check a linear algebra book for details).

Comment: The matrix $M$ is simple, $MM^T=I$ should help you 'see' the inverse of $C$ in terms of those of $D$ and $A$.

Comment: @Berci, I don't understand what "column space of $B$ is invariant under $A$" means. I googled to no avail.

Comment: @WillJagy, I edited my question to answer yours.

Comment: @Any, There's no $M$ or $D$ in my question... I'm guessing your $D$ is my $B$, but I'm not sure what you mean otherwise.

Comment: You said that $B$ is obtained in such and such a way. To me that means that $B$ can be written as I suggested.

Comment: scott, as i expected. You may be able to do something with a Cholesky decomposition for your $A.$ In brief, it depends on the extent to which $B$ resembles a section of an orthogonal matrix.